# js get tag with same tagName

Tags: javascript, tags

Is there a way to get the collection of tags that have the same name?

Somenthing like:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var a = 0; a < buttons['item-menu-edit-button'].length; a++) {
  sys.addEventHandler(buttons['item-menu-edit-button'][a], 'click', callback);
}
```

I need to assign an event handler to every edit button...

[edit]
the html markup is:

```
<span>
<button name="item-menu-edit-button" id="generiID">Edit</button>
<!-- content -->
</span>
<span>
<button name="item-menu-edit-button" id="generiID">Edit</button>
<!-- other content -->
</span>
```

I need to assign an event handler for "click" events on every button named "item-menu-edit-button".

Comment: The way to get elements with the same tag name is `getElementsByTagName` which you seem to already know about.  Perhaps you could expand on what your actual issue is.  Do you need the same tag name AND the same `name` attribute?

Comment: and please post the HTML markup as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using functions/keywords from a different language, there is no function `addEventHandler` in javascript. The built in function for what your wanting to do is `addEventListener`. Also I am unsure what `sys` is but they way you have written your code you are trying to add an event handler to a object called `sys` instead of your buttons.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    if(buttons[i].getAttribute('name') == 'item-menu-edit-button'){
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', callback);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** As per your comment updated so that it assigns for buttons matching the `name` attribute.

Comment: the markup is simple.. Oppss sorry "auto add post".. :)

<button name="item-menu-edit-button" id="-genericID">Edit</button>
<button name="item-menu-edit-button" id="-genericID">Edit</button>

I use the same button for the same event.. I don't want to add class or work with class that's a style problem..

I need to assign an event to every button with the name attribute = item-menu-edit-button

Comment: the sys.addEventHandler is mine.. handle the addEventListener/attachEvent issue

Comment: @user2179751 be sure to mark the answer accepted if it solved your problem. It will encourage others later on to help you.